# Blender Nodes in Editor doesn't show preview Image

Tags: rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a small problem with my blender lately. I want to make some compositing with my compositing nodes but the problem is, blender won't show me the preview Image. I have a Screenshot for you guys.

[image]

The preview Image itself is enabled, but it just won't show.

Thanks for your help in advance!

-Marten

Comment: Have you rendered your scene? (F12 or the camera button on the renderlayers node)

Comment: @gandalf3 oh no! Is it necessary to do so? ... I am sorry, but I am new to Nodes.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the compositor nodes don't have anything to operate on (unless you add another input source besides the renderlayers node).

Comment: @gandalf3 btw, I read the other post about the preview Issue, but there was a white X and in my Case there was no white X so I thought it must be something different. But well, it worked so, thanks!

Comment: The white X only appears when the viewer node is selected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to render the scene before anything shows on the compositor. Hit<kbd>F12</kbd> or press **Render**.
[image]

To have the **Viewer Node**'s image as background behind the node tree you need to enable the backdrop button:

[image]

If you press <kbd>N</kbd> on the Node Editor's window  you'll see Controls for size and placement of the backdrop:

[image]

Or you can zoom in and out by pressing <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

You can also choose to see the **Composite Node** or **Viewer Node** in a **UV/Image Editor** window.
Selecting **Render Result** will display the **Composite Node**

[image]