# Renders doesn't display in Node Editor while compositing

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, node-editor, render-layers

I follow that tutorial step by step:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3sSZ6W7rgQ
and had to stop around 44:00 - I had rendered my image and when I go into Node Editor there is no way to make backdrop shows up. I don't know what's going on. I'm using Blender v2.71. Please help me :)

Comment: Do you have backdrop checked and your render layers connected to a viewer node?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: I had backdrop checked but I didn't connect my render layers to a viewer nodes :) In the tutorial he turn on Node Editor and after checking backdrop everything works, but not for me so I stopped. After I connected this everything works fine :) Thanks

Comment: no prob, sadly since I didn't actually answer the question I don't get the extra reputation but that's ok. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Note: You can *Ctrl - click* on a node to quickly connect it to the viewer node.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14971/599

Answer (score 2):

TARDIS Maker comment is a solution to my problem, I just didn't connect render layers to a viewer node.